# Изменить значения определенного ключа в многомерном массиве

Tags: php, массивы, woocommerce

Нужно изменить значения ключа [sku] в массиве arr на значения из массива arr2. Результат должен быть следующим:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [sku] =>9404 [stockQuantity] => 10 [incoming] => [prices] => ) [1] => Array ( [sku] =>9401 [stockQuantity] => 15 [incoming] => [prices] => ))
```

Ниже код, но он работает не совсем правильно. Как достичь нужного результата?

`wc_get_product_id_by_sku` это функция Woocommerce, которая возвращает в переменную $id значение ID товара в соответствии с sku товара.

```
$data = '[
  {
    "sku": "NPQ10",
    "stockQuantity": 10,
    "incoming": null,
    "prices": null
  },
  {
    "sku": "WS11",
    "stockQuantity": 15,
    "incoming": null,
    "prices": null
    }
]';
  
$arr = json_decode($data, true);
$arr2 = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) { 
    $id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku($arr[$i][sku]);
    array_push($arr2,$id);
}
for($j = 0; $j <= count($arr2); $j++) {
    foreach ($arr as &$entry) {
        foreach ($entry as $key => &$val) {
            if ($key == "sku") {
                $val=$arr2[$j];
            }
        }
   }
}
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я не совсем понял задачу, но подозреваю, что нужно модифицировать ключи `sku`.

Это можно сделать намного проще, чем вы предлагаете, используя всего один цикл:

```
$data = '[
  {
    "sku": "NPQ10",
    "stockQuantity": 10,
    "incoming": null,
    "prices": null
  },
  {
    "sku": "WS11",
    "stockQuantity": 15,
    "incoming": null,
    "prices": null
    }
]';

$data = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($data as &$item) {
    // ниже вы должны использовать свою функцию
    $item['sku'] = "modify-{$item['sku']}";
}

var_export($data);
```

Итог:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'sku' => 'modify-NPQ10',
    'stockQuantity' => 10,
    'incoming' => NULL,
    'prices' => NULL,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'sku' => 'modify-WS11',
    'stockQuantity' => 15,
    'incoming' => NULL,
    'prices' => NULL,
  ),
)
```